# Como hacer echo de una variable superglobal en HTML

Tags: php, html5

Tengo una variable superglobal $_SESSION con un valor dentro y quiero hacer un echo en una pagina HTML pero no me aparece nada. Mi codigo es el siguiente :

```
<header class='main' id='h1'>
  <span class="right"><a href="layout.html">LogOut</a> </span> 
  <?php echo $_SESSION['login']; ?>
<h2>Quiz: crazy questions</h2>
</header>
```

La cosa es que el echo no se ejecuta. Alguien sabe arreglarlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la parte inferior de tu sitio tienes que poner la siguiente sentencia:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

> Supongo claramente que la variable `$_SESSION` la estas asignando desde un login.

Tu codigo html si debe quedar asi como lo tienes:

```
<header class='main' id='h1'>
  <span class="right"><a href="layout.html">LogOut</a> </span> 
  <?php echo $_SESSION['login']; ?>
<h2>Quiz: crazy questions</h2>
</header>
```

Ejemplo:

```
<?php session_start();
$_SESSION['login'] = "wilson";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class='main' id='h1'>
      <span class="right"><a href="layout.html">LogOut</a> </span> 
      <?php echo $_SESSION['login']; ?>
    <h2>Quiz: crazy questions</h2>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Puedes comprobar que existe tu variable `$_SESSION` con la siguiente condicional:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["login"]))  
 {  
    echo "No existe o no esta seteada la SESSION";
    die();  
 }else {
    echo "La SESSION login si existe $_SESSION['login']";
}
```

Esa condicional la debes poner justo **después** del `session_start();`, siempre va de primero de todo el `session_start();`

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar y esta igual.

Comment: tu archivo tiene la extension .php verdad?, voy a actualizar mi ejemplo para que pruebes, por cierto no te arroja ningún error?

Comment: Listo, fue actualizado mi ejemplo, por favor revisa primero que todo que la extension sea .php y no .html . htm

Comment: Menudo despiste el problema era la extension que estaba en html en vez de php. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Vale no te preocupes, estamos para servir, me alegra que te haya funcionado, saludos.